# Jupyter-Notebook (.ipynb) Cells Scroll Horizontally NOT Vertically

Tags: jupyter-notebook, scroll

I'm Running: Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4, Python: 3.10 on Linux Mint 22.04
On GitHub, my Jupyter Notebook started to display the cells at the end of my (.ipynb) page horizontally, not vertically.

Like so:
[image]

When I run the .ipynb on my laptop, I see the page vertically as it should be. I tried and could not find the keywords that brought me to the right problem and answer.

I cannot find the proper reference help.

Comment: Most people don't realize that GitHub's support for notebooks, although radicallly improved over the years, is not good and should be treated as nothing more than a rough preview. The Jupyter community provides a viewer that supports things much better and even renders interactive Plotly plots and other things that have javascript underlying them, whereas GitHub doesn't. Plus it is suitable for sharing with non-developers. Does it work better if you put the URL in [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) and point it at your notebook and view it? (Examine result URL for the pattern to skip the form.)

Comment: Wayne, thanks. Did not know that. nbviewer does not correct the issue. I'll try converting it to PDF and then uploading it.

Comment: Sorry, trying nbviewer didn't fix it. Still, it's good to know that is a better choice for rendering 'static' notebooks after they've been run. (I put 'static' in quotes because as I pointed out earlier, some of the interactive elements remain active in nbviewer, unlike GitHub.) I wonder if there is just some special about the latex use involved here. There wasn't any embedded special formatting of css?

Comment: I quickly looked for CSS that might change the output format, but nothing struck me as flagrantly wrong.