# Download Jupyter notebook .ipynb as html

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

When i download .ipynb file using file-->download as html, i get the format as the below screenshot. Each code block get stacked horizontally instead of vertically. I am using jupyter lab using anaconda

[image]

Comment: Odd. I remember recently seeing somebody report something similar [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76781572/8508004); however, I don't think that was when the saved it as HTML. Is it only this file that does it? If it isn't could you share actual HTML code via a code posting /snippet-posting site such as GitHub's gist or something place similar?

Comment: How recent is your Anaconda install? Has this always been the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nbconvert` module to convert jupyter-notebook to HTML.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
```

Edit: nbconvert is integrated with jupyter as @Wayne mentioned.

Comment: when i run this: `jupyter nbconvert --to html finalproject.ipynb` in jupyter notebook, getting invalid syntax error

Comment: Jupyter has `jupyter nbconvert` integrated so there is no need for the install you mention, Aman.

Comment: You'd need to run `jupyter nbconvert --to html finalproject.ipynb` in the terminal, @Ussu20 . Or add an exclamation point in front of it in order to run it inside a Jupyter cell.

Comment: the format is still wrong, get horizontally stacked

Comment: That makes sense because it is using the same command behind the scenes most likely. But it was worth trying.

Comment: can you add `--template lab` as well? `jupyter nbconvert --to html --template lab finalproject.ipynb`.